# Why can the dimension of a subspace be less than the number of vectors in the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that all bases have to have the same dimension.

But suppose a subspace *W* is spanned by (0, 0, 1), so the dimension of this subspace is 1. But isn't the standard basis {(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)}, which has dimension 3, also a valid basis for *W*?

How is this difference in dimension explained? Or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: it cannot be less than the number of vectors of a basis, what you gives is not a basis of $W$ because it span $\mathbb{R}^3$ and not $W$

Comment: "I understand that all bases have to have the same dimension" ,just to clarify: bases have no dimension, vector spaces have a dimension, which is the cardinality of a basis, this is well defined since all bases of a space have the same cardinality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because a basis needs to consist of elements of that subspace.